# Silex: Calling $app->abort() in a middleware returns 500

Tags: php, pdo, silex

I don't want to use Doctrine or etc. So, I simply use the PDO. The problem is that I dont't know how to handle the exception: calling the `$app->abort` to show it doesn't work outside the routes.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app = new Silex\Application();

//PDO
try {
    $DBH = new PDO($PartCCTV_ini['db']['dsn'], $PartCCTV_ini['db']['user'], $PartCCTV_ini['db']['password']);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $app->abort(500, 'PDO Error : '.$e->getMessage());            
} 

...

$app->run()

?>
```

Comment: What result do you expect? And by the way, why are you doing this outside of application instead of creating a service for that?

Comment: @dragoste, error page with exit code 500 and explanation. Writing a service will take too much time, I think.

Comment: Simply return proper header  like `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');` and then you may also post any html content of 500 error page. But you can't use Silex application here since you do it before it starts.

Comment: And how about special array for exceptions? Can Silex parse it and show an error page if there are any errors in array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//PDO
try {
    $DBH = new PDO($PartCCTV_ini['db']['dsn'], $PartCCTV_ini['db']['user'], $PartCCTV_ini['db']['password']);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $Exception = $e->getMessage();    
    $app->before(function () use($Exception) {
        throw new PDOException($Exception);
    });
}
```

***"Kolkhoz-style"*** (*Russian*), but it works!